# Ldap cannot access entryCSN or timestamps

Tags: c#, ldap

I am using a LDAP phone book on a PBX and I am trying to access the whenCreated or entryCSN properties of a user. I can see them in my LDAP explorer but cannot read the properties I am after. Only certain properties are accessible such a telephone number.

Why would this be?
With the code below I can get all the values but not the ones I am after

```
string telephone = child.Properties["telephoneNumber"].Value.ToString();
string name = child.Properties["cn"].Value.ToString();
```

But I cannot get `whenCreated` or `entryCSN` to work

**Code:**

```
foreach (DirectoryEntry child in domain.Children)
{

    foreach (string propName in child.Properties.PropertyNames)
    {

        if (child.Properties[propName].Value != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(propName + " = " + child.Properties[propName].Value);
            //child.SchemaEntry.Properties.PropertyNames 
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(propName + " = NULL");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information. For example it would be nice to know what PBX you are using and the code that you are struggling with

Comment: Asterisk based PBX. Yeastar to be specific. the code I'm using is basically:  Accessing the properties of child.properties from domain.children

Comment: Please post the code. Simply telling us about it does not give us enough information to be able to help you. Please edit your post and post your code in your question. [This article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) will help you format your code in the post

Comment: The line "   child.SchemaEntry.Properties.PropertyNames " is a mistake I have commented that out in the actual code

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: when i try to access entryCSN. a property i can see in my ldap browser I get:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.Value.get returned null.

Comment: Try adding `if(child == null){continue;}` after the first foreach loop is declared and before the second one is declared.

Comment: Still get a null error. I dont understand how my ldap browser can access the properties like entryCSN but in code I cannot could it be the authentication method?

Comment: When you do a watch can you see any values in any of the variables in the for loops?

Comment: yes, I can access telephoneNumber, cn, sn, mail and a couple others but nothing with a timestamp which is what im after

Comment: Are you using any libraries or packages?

Comment: just using System.DirectoryServices

Comment: Hmmm I am not sure where you are getting this error. If you try to access the property directly (`child.Properties["timestamp"].Value.ToString();`) it still fails?

Comment: Using: child.Properties["modifyTimestamp"].Value.ToString(); which I can see in my ldap explorer that has a value of 20171051225651Z I get a null error

Comment: Personally, I would code a special case when that property comes up to just run `child.Properties["modifyTimestamp"].Value.ToString();` instead of relying upon the `child.Properties[propName].Value`. However, that is not really a fantastic way to go about it. The next step to debugging is checking to see if the property name in the for loop does not match `modifyTimestamp` exactly

Comment: Yes I can do that its just seems these properties require admin access or soemthing I am logging in as admin

Comment: Did that fix it for you?

Comment: I had to apply database logic in the end. i.e the latest items will always be in the largest index. It seems I just cant access those date fields at all.